# Rails 4 form_tag submitting to wrong controller action

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, routes, ruby-2.0

This feels dumb, but so far everything I've read makes me feel like I'm doing it right but it's still not working.

I'm using a form_tag to submit params to a custom controller action. Instead of the action I indicate, it seems intents on submitting to the `show` action in my controller, which I need to reserve for profiles. Anyways here's the code (please excuse it's un-refactored state):

Doctors controller:

```
class DoctorsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def show
    @doctor_list = Doctor.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @doctor_list = Doctor.all
  end

  def search
  end

  def results
    if params[:zip] && params[:zip].length === 5 && params[:zip]
      @doctor_list = Doctor.where("zip = ?", params[:zip])
    elsif params[:id]
      begin
        @doctor_list = []
        @doctor_list<<Doctor.find(params[:id])
      rescue
        flash.now[:errors] = "That doctor does not exist!"
        render 'search'
      end
    else
      flash.now[:errors] = "That is not a valid zipcode!"
      render 'search'
    end
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
  resources :users
  resources :doctors

  root 'doctors#search'
  get 'doctors/results' => 'doctors#results'
```

search.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, "Home") %>

<div class="hero">
  <h1>Find an M.D.</h1>

  <%= form_tag(doctors_results_path, method: "get") do %>
    <%= label_tag("Zipcode: ") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:zip) %><br>

    <%= submit_tag "FIND", class: "button"%>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Again, the issue is that I'm getting an error (`Couldn't find Doctor with 'id'=results`) because the form is using my show action vs. my results action. The application trace says the error is located at `app/controllers/doctors_controller.rb:6:in 'show'`. As an added confusion, I don't *really* understand why it's sending `"id"=>"results"` as part of the params hash on submit, but it seems like that might be a non-issue if it would use the correct controller action to begin with.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Try moving `get 'doctors/results' => 'doctors#results'` above `resources :doctors`

Comment: @Pavan Ugh, that was all. Just a priority issue? Since resources :doctors was first, it gave priority to that (and therefor the show action) instead of what I was telling it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its a priority issue. Since the `resources :doctors` is first, the `GET show` will be given the priority than `get 'doctors/results' => 'doctors#results'`

Moving the get `'doctors/results' => 'doctors#results'` above `resources :doctors` should solve your problem

```
#routes.rb
root 'doctors#search'
get 'doctors/results' => 'doctors#results'

resources :users
resources :doctors
```